# Bitcoin core imported wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, backup, bech32-address, import

I have a friend that has an issue with his core: He generated a wallet with coldcard, imported in bitcoin core.. received on both bech32 addresses and nested ones. Lost access to that pc and now when he imports the wallet again to a new Core he can see only the bech32 transactions. Can someone explain how to get to the nested ones as well?